# Javascript: indexOf() & substr() not returning expected result on date string

Tags: javascript, string, function

In the image you will see the value being passed in and all the string functions I tried, but nothing seems to be working. I even tried putting it into a variable via new Date(d), but got "Invalid Date". I also tried using trim(). If I hard-coded a date string as the value for "d" then everything functioned as expected.
Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?
[Image: JS console.log of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNHbg.png)

```
function convertDate2ISO(dateToConvert){
    var strDate = dateToConvert.trim();
    if (dateToConvert.indexOf("-") > 0) { strDate = dateToConvert.replace(/-/g, ' ');}

    if (dateToConvert.indexOf("/") > 0) {
        var substrValue = dateToConvert.substr(0,3);
        var indexOfValue = dateToConvert.indexOf('/');
        var toStringIndexOfValue = dateToConvert.toString().indexOf('/');
        var sliceValue = dateToConvert.slice(0,2);
        console.log("Incoming value (dateToConvert): " + dateToConvert + "\r\n" + "Using dateToConvert.substr(0,3): " +substrValue+ "\r\nUsing dateToConvert.indexOf('/'): " +indexOfValue+ "\r\nUsing dateToConvert.toString().indexOf('/'): " +toStringIndexOfValue+ "\r\nUsing dateToConvert.slice(0,2): " +sliceValue+ "\r\nUsing dateToConvert.length: " +dateToConvert.length );
        //was trying to use dateToConvert.indexOf('/') to test on, but result was unexpected
        //add 0 to begining if month is a singel digit 
        strDate = "0" + strDate;
    }

    var myDate = new Date(strDate);
    myDate.toISOString(); //"2011-23-12T15:28:46.493Z
    return myDate
}
```

The default for the incoming parameter is...

```
var myDateObj = new Date();
var strDTGReceived = myDateObj.toLocaleDateString();
```

The call to the function is...

```
var dtISOReceivedDate = convertDate2ISO(strDTGReceived);
```

Values I am getting are...

```
Incoming Parameter (dateToConvert): 2/18/2020
Using dateToConvert.substr(0,3): ‎2‎
dateToConvert.indexOf('/'): 3
Using dateToConvert.toString().indexOf('/'): 3
Using dateToConvert.slice(0,2): ‎2
Using dateToConvert.length: 14
```

Comment: Please update your question to include your attempts and we will be able to provide more help :)

Comment: If you have text, then please post that, instead of images of text. It would be even better if you can provide a reproducible code so we can see the issue. Right now I can only guess there are whitespace characters but it's not really possible to say.

Comment: @Brugui was correct about date vs myDate variable, but I am still getting the same results (see below). This must mean that I am not passing in a string, even though the string functions are working on it.
Incoming value (d): ‎2‎/‎18‎/‎2020
Using d.substr(0,3): ‎2‎
Using d.indexOf('/'): 3
Using d.toString().indexOf('/'): 3
Using d.slice(0,2): ‎2

Comment: The length of the incoming parameter is 14.... way to long.

Comment: Where do you call the convertDate function?, what value are you setting as the argument, and what value is logged to the console when you console.log(dateToConvert) at the top of the convertDate function? Is it something like '2/18/2020', or a number like 0.000055005500550055004

Comment: @Spangle - Sorry updated the function name to convertDate2ISO. The argument is set via var myDateObj = new Date(); var strDTGReceived = myDateObj.toLocaleDateString(); dateToCovert argument is logged as "2/19/2020" at top of function. Also note that string functions are working so I believe it sees it as a string, but just giving the wrong results. I do not know why it is seen as "2/19/2020" but shows it as 14 chars long.

Comment: The problem was .toLocaleDateString(); which was returning different formats of the date, Once I treated it as a date object and just built the string via get month, day and year from the date it worked as it should. Still think it was weird that the extra characters were not visible, but problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on your function when you try to use and return the `date` variable when you defined it as `myDate`.

Changing that, your code should work as shown here:

```js
function convertDate(d){
        var strDate = d;
        if (d.indexOf("-") > 0) { 
          strDate = d.replace(/-/g, ' ');
        }

        if (d.indexOf("/") > 0) {
            var substrValue = d.substr(0,3);
            var indexOfValue = d.indexOf('/');
            var toStringIndexOfValue = d.toString().indexOf('/');
            var sliceValue = d.slice(0,2);
            console.log("Incoming value (d): " + d + "\r\n" + "Using d.substr(0,3): " +substrValue+ "\r\nUsing d.indexOf('/'): " +indexOfValue+ "\r\nUsing d.toString().indexOf('/'): " +toStringIndexOfValue+ "\r\nUsing d.slice(0,2): " +sliceValue );
            strDate = "0" + strDate;
        }

        var myDate = new Date(strDate);
        myDate.toISOString(); 
        return myDate 
    }
    
 console.log('Result: ' +convertDate('2/18/2020'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertDate( d ) {
        var myDate = new Date( d );
            if( "" + myDate == "Invalid Date" )return console.info("Invalid Date Format!");
        return myDate.toISOString();
    }
    
     console.log('Result: ' + convertDate('2m18d2020'));
     console.log('Result: ' + convertDate('2/18/2020'));
     console.log('Result: ' + convertDate('2 18 2020'));
     console.log('Result: ' + convertDate('2-18-2020'));
     console.log('Result: ' + convertDate('2.18.2020'));
```

You should always try to keep things as simple as possible.

```
function convertDate( d ) {
    var myDate = new Date( d );
        if( "" + myDate == "Invalid Date" )return console.info("Invalid Date Format!");
    return myDate.toISOString();
}
```

This approach will accept any useful date literal and will not be limited only to "/"and "-", but will be able to accept all of the commonly used separators: white-space, comma, dot, included.